# Why 'var imp : = _' not compile?

Tags: scala

Why do initialisations need the object type :

Why does this compile :

```
var imp : String = _
```

But this does not :

```
var imp = _
```

with error : `unbound placeholder parameter`

Is it because the object type is not known at initialisation time ?

Comment: nor var imp : String = _ nor var imp = _ nor var imp:Any = _ is something that is typically considered as proper scala code, you should avoid mutability and Any as much as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `var imp : String = _`, Scala knows that `imp` is a String, even if it doesn't have a value (it initializes it to `null`).

When you write `var imp = _`, Scala has no idea what the type is.  It can only know the intended type if you either specify it explicitly or give an initial value from which it can be inferred.

Comment: could it not initalise it to type Any with value of null and then convert it using type inference when its used to type String ?

Comment: @user470184 hypothetically speaking this could be done, but it's a huge source of potential errors and odds: e.g. what if somebody just leaves var x = _ and provide no more assigments, what if ... and so on. It's not that hard to write `var x: Any = _` or `var x: String = _` in such relatively rare cases.

Comment: @om-nom-nom "what if somebody just leaves var x = _ and provide no more assigments" why should this matter ? is this not the issue as saying 'var x : String = _' and providing no more assignments ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- it's because the object type is not known at declaration/initalization time.